# Unable to use an embedded binary in a different scheme xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm following the tutorial here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-managing-configurations-with-ease--mobile-18324

I've setup some a few schemes to manage dev / staging / prod, but whenever I try to compile any of these schemes, I get an error:

> No such module Alamofire

If I change back to the default scheme, it compiles fine. Do I need to take any additional steps when setting up schemes to embed a binary?

[image: Build Configuration]
[image: Alamofire]
[image: Embedded Binaries]

Comment: What Build Configurations do the schemes utilize?

Comment: I created build configurations for each of the schemes (dev/staging/prod) by duplicating the Debug build configuration. The debug build configuration had Alamofire in it beforehand. I've attached an image to show what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the issue here is that Alamofire does not have the defined scheme. Xcode doesn't Create the same named scheme for Alamofire. You can point those scheme to the appropriate Alamofire configuration (Debug or Release) based on the environment. For example, the Development scheme would probably use the Debug version of Alamofire. You will probably have to delete the Derived Data directory (you can do this in the Organizer).

If this doesn't work you may need to actually add the the configuration to Alamofire as well. Which, if you have to do that, then you'll need to make sure make the AF scheme use the right configuration.

You also need to make sure that you have Alamofire in the scheme's Build target list.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had to create a "development", "staging", and "production" scheme for Alamofire and it compiled OK for each scheme. I didn't have to delete any derived data.